# Get textbox HTML and value with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a text box in a div:

```
<div id="divTest">
    <input type="text" id="txtText">
</div>
```

Suppose the user types a word into the text box, I want a jquery method of getting the textbox HTML **with the value** that the user typed in. I have tried the below code:

```
$('#btnTest').click(function(){
    alert($('#divTest').html());
    e.preventDefault();
});​
```

But this only gives me the HTML of the textbox, not the HTML + the value of the text within the textbox.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GYwf3/) is a jsFiddle of the problem.

Comment: Do you want the html of the input too?

Comment: Yes, I want the HTML of the input with the embedded value

Comment: you mean something like (only IE) .outerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var html_input = $("#divTest").html();
var val = $("#txtText").val();
var input = html_input.slice(0,-1) + " value='" + val + "'>";
alert(input);
```

Comment: Ok, that does work for this one example. But it doesn't scale to other input elements or if there are multiple input elements in the div.

Comment: @Coltech: Ok, you didn't say multiple inputs.  Just use .each() and get the val and html and input for each case.

Comment: @Coltech: You can use `split()` to split the html_input for the '>' separator in the string returned by `$("#divTest").html()` into an array, and retrieve html_input for each case using the `index` of `$("#divTest :input").each(function(index) {etc.})`

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = $('#divTest').html();
var value = $('#divTest').val();
var message = html + value;
```

Comment: That won't work, you would be appending the value to the HTML, which would look something like `<input type="text" name="name" />value`    

He is looking for `<input type="text" name="name" value="value" />`

Comment: Sorry that wont work, that just concatenates the input value onto the end of the HTML. I want the HTML with the embedded value so it will render properly.

Comment: I don't think there is a function to extract both values and html at the same time. I would get the html, declare and array, loop through each character of the html until you get the '>' , then you add "Value =" value and concatenates what's left of the characters.